# Unity : UI Elements out of Camera .. (all images & Code inside)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I finished my first simple 2D game finally .. but now i hit a wall .. i'm trying to adjust the game for multiple screens (Android ) . I build the game on 1080 x 1920 resolution.. And now to make it adapt with different screens resolutions i used this Code and its working for me ..

```
public class ControllingCameraAspectScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        // set the desired aspect ratio (the values in this example are
        // hard-coded for 16:9, but you could make them into public
        // variables instead so you can set them at design time)
        float targetaspect = 1080.0f / 1920.0f;

        // determine the game window's current aspect ratio
        float windowaspect = (float)Screen.width / (float)Screen.height;

        // current viewport height should be scaled by this amount
        float scaleheight = windowaspect / targetaspect;

        // obtain camera component so we can modify its viewport
        Camera camera = GetComponent<Camera>();

        // if scaled height is less than current height, add letterbox
        if (scaleheight < 1.0f)
        {
            Rect rect = camera.rect;

            rect.width = 1.0f;
            rect.height = scaleheight;
            rect.x = 0;
            rect.y = (1.0f - scaleheight) / 2.0f;

            camera.rect = rect;
        }
        else // add pillarbox
        {
            float scalewidth = 1.0f / scaleheight;

            Rect rect = camera.rect;

            rect.width = scalewidth;
            rect.height = 1.0f;
            rect.x = (1.0f - scalewidth) / 2.0f;
            rect.y = 0;

            camera.rect = rect;
        }
    }

}
```

thank god the Game Objects in place .. but the UI Elements out of the Camera .. please look to the images ..

[This is 1080 x 1920 .. my original work .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buwZ4.png)

[and this is on another device 1536 x 2048 ..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kk63.png)

And i'm already using Canvas Scaler and Anchors with UI elements ..

Comment: Post a screenshot of your Canvas Scaler settings

Comment: Hi, the UI Elements is not out of the Camera.  
The problem here is you 2D graphics that not fill the width of screen.  
(As you can see in your pic, there are two black borders)  

So you need to write a code that based on width and height of screen, maintain aspect ratio.

Comment: this is the canvas settings .. http://imgur.com/r5753Mf

Comment: @SteeBono  can you help me with that please .. ? if i can just edit my Camera Code ?

Comment: @HaniDarker First thing that you can try is to set:
- Screen Match Mode: Width
- Match: 0

With these changes the width of the game fits always the width.
After that you only need to fit height for example increasing the height of your background

Comment: @HaniDarker [Check this example](http://imgur.com/a/04RAc)

Comment: @SteeBono look nothing changed http://imgur.com/A4OmHFB

Comment: @HaniDarker try to change the Screen Match Mode to Shrink

Comment: @HaniDarker Change Galaxy S2 screen to your 1080x1920 screen and check if you have black borders.

If you have black borders with your original screen size, you only need to change the distance of camera until black borders disappear.

Comment: @SteeBono http://imgur.com/RUEPpMk

Comment: @HaniDarker I have noticed that you have changed the screen resolution.
But you must maintain Match to 0.

And you have to adjust the camera, keeping match equal to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution i found for my problem is to follow this tutorial ..

http://gamedesigntheory.blogspot.ie/2010/09/controlling-aspect-ratio-in-unity.html

Answer (score 0):

In **Canvas Scaler** component, you can set its **UI Scale Mode** to **Scale With Screen Size**.

[more information](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html)